# @media print css issue

Tags: css, height

I have added media print css like this

```
@media print
{
    div#file1 {
        height: 100%!important;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
}
```

Problem is that it is working fine in firefox but not in chrome while printing. it doesn't take height in chrome. WHen i try to give min-height: 100% to div then it is working but print only visible area not after scroll.

Comment: When using `height: 100%`, you should set the height of the parent element. Have you done that?

Comment: If you need to print whole text without scroll, you may try `overflow: auto`

Comment: @Ovilia : Yes, i done that but it is not working. Height: 100% working in FF but not in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified you want a scrollbar on your div as well as the one normally on the browser and this can be done as:

```
 @media print { 
       div#file1{ 
           height: 100%!important; 
           overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
           overflow-y: scroll;
           overflow-x: hidden;
        } 
 }
```

This would resolve your issue